# Mouse events not triggering in user control

Tags: vb.net, windows-mobile-6.5

I've created a user control that inherits from the treeview class.  Most events are triggered properly such as key-events and other treeview-specific events.  Mouse events, however, are not triggered at all by the touchscreen as my readings have indicated they should.  This is a visual basic .NET 3.5 CE application running on Windows Mobile Pro 6.5.3.

Comment: That's a good description, but you have only made statements and haven't asked a question. Also, for you to get a good answer you really should provide us with enough code to **easily** replicate your issue. Otherwise we're just guessing what's going on here. Good questions usually get good answers within minutes of being asked. Have a read of [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Fair enough... Long day... My question is how to receive the mouse events for the tree view.  Subscribing to the events in the user control's class module does not seem to be enough.  I'll post whatever code anyone thinks may be helpful, but I'm not sure what that would be at this point.

Comment: I assume you created a subclass of the treeview, not a user conrol. Ther is a blog describing the mouse events, ie TreeNodeMouseClickEventHandler (see  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/netcfteam/2005/05/23/subclassing-controls-in-netcf-2-0-part-2/). BTW: there is a difference in creating a user control and placing a treeview inside OR creating a subclass of the treeview...Show your code

Comment: The user control was created as a separate project with the main class inheriting from tree view then placed at design time in the application project as an instance of that control. The pertinent code being: Inherits Tree view. The rest of the code is just standard methods and functions that have no effect on the class itself. I'll take a look at your article... Thank you!